# Indenting a block of equations correctly

Tags: indentation

I have the following code

```
\begin{equation*}

P1: c_2=c_5;\\
P2: a_6=c_1;\\
P3: a_2=c_5;\\
P4: b_6=b_2;\\
P5: a_7+b_7=a_2+b_2;\\
P6: a_6+b_6=a_3+b_3;\\
P7: a_7=a_3;\\
P8: c_8=b_3;\\
P9: b_7=c_4;\\
P10: c_4=c_8
\end{equation*}\\
```

When I compile it, it looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove the space before P1, and cannot find a way to do so. How can I remove it?

Comment: That is not using math mode _at all_ the equation ends at the blank line before the text. If you get error, as you do here, ask about the _error_  . Any output you get after an error is at best usable for debugging it is not intended to produce a usable document.

Answer (score 4):

You should never skip lines in the `equation*` environment. In fact, there are dedicated environments for multi-line display math, like `align` and `gather`.

For your specific case, I'd use `align*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
P1 & : c_2=c_5;\\
P2 & : a_6=c_1;\\
P3 & : a_2=c_5;\\
P4 & : b_6=b_2;\\
P5 & : a_7+b_7=a_2+b_2;\\
P6 & : a_6+b_6=a_3+b_3;\\
P7 & : a_7=a_3;\\
P8 & : c_8=b_3;\\
P9 & : b_7=c_4;\\
P10 & : c_4=c_8
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]